# How to get the recombined vectors efficiently?

Tags: r, vector

Given two axises, both with positions from 1 to N (N can be several millions, but we assume N = 1000 here),
there are two vectors recording the positions of some points on the two axises, respectively. For example:

```
chrm1 <- c(1, 35, 456, 732) # 4 points on axis 1 at position 1, 35, 456, 732;
chrm2 <- c(23, 501, 980)
```

if recombination at position 300 of the two axis, points behind 300 on the two axises will switch to the other axis.
the two vectors recording position of points will become :

```
chrm1 <- c(1, 35, 501, 980)
chrm2 <- c(23, 456, 732)
```

if a second recombination occurs at 600, the new vectors will be:

```
chrm1 <- c(1, 35, 501, 732)
chrm2 <- c(23, 456, 980)
```

the real data looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
chrm1 <- sample.int(1e8, 50)
chrm2 <- sample.int(1e8, 50)
breaks.site <- sample.int(1e8, 5)
```

My brute-force way was to swap points into the other vector for each breaks sites. But this is quite slow, because I have to do this for 2 x 1000 x 20000 times.
How to get the recombined vectors efficiently?

```
for(i in breaks.site){
    chrm1.new <- c(chrm1[chrm1 < i], chrm2[chrm2 > i])
    chrm2.new <- c(chrm1[chrm1 > i], chrm2[chrm2 < i])
    chrm1 <- chrm1.new
    chrm2 <- chrm2.new
}
```

background about recombination:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_recombination

Comment: Why are the vectors of different length if they describe points?

Comment: What's your brute force way?

Comment: @aichao, I think that I have make the logic clear with the short examples and what happens at each step.

Comment: @Roland, these points are randomly distributed on the two axises. And it need not to be of same numbers. One axis could have more points than the other.

Comment: @alistaire, see my edit.

Comment: Is the input sorted or unsorted? Is order of the results important?

Comment: @Roland, the order does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
chrm1 <- c(1, 35, 456, 732) 
chrm2 <- c(23, 501, 980)


breaks <- c(300, 600)

#check all points for all breaks, 
#get sum of position changes and
#calculate x mod 2
changepos1 <- rowSums(outer(chrm1, breaks, ">")) %% 2
changepos2 <- rowSums(outer(chrm2, breaks, ">")) %% 2

#assemble results and sort
res1 <- sort(c(chrm1[!changepos1], chrm2[as.logical(changepos2)]))
#[1]   1  35 501 732
res2 <- sort(c(chrm2[!changepos2], chrm1[as.logical(changepos1)]))
#[1]  23 456 980
```

If `outer` needs to much memory due to the size of your problem, you can use a loop instead.

Comment: I did a little benchmark with the `microbenchmark` package. This way is actually slower (mean 116ms) than the brute-force way (mean 52ms) when applied to the longer example  data in my question for 1000 times.

Comment: OK. We are talking about microseconds here, right? Then your best bet is implementing it in Rcpp, which is rather simple for this algorithm.

Comment: The sort is slow. when I removed that, the speed is similar. I haven't touched  C or C++ after college course :(. It is time to pick up. I'll give my vote for this answer.